# Insert 0 in database when a textbox is found empty

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a windows form application, in which there are some textboxes. I want to insert 0 in database if a textbox is empty else insert the value given in textbox. So far what I have done is checking each textbox separately. But I want to do this with a function.

My code is:

```
if (other == "")
{
   adp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@otherDeduct", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 0;
   otherDeduct = 0.0M;
}
else
{
   adp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@otherDeduct", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOtherDeduct.Text);
   otherDeduct = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOtherDeduct.Text);
}

if (tax == "")
{
   adp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@taxDeduct", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 0;
   taxDeduct = 0.0M;
}
else
{
   adp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@taxDeduct", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTaxDeduct.Text);
   taxDeduct = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTaxDeduct.Text);
}
```

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Why do you want to add `int` and `decimal` to your `SqlDbType.VarChar` column?

Comment: What's the problem with your code? You did not ask a question.

Comment: textbox values are needed for some calculation, that's why.

Comment: @user3497389 but calculating numbers from `varchars` is so unnecessarily hard, that's what Soner wanted to point out, you get the values from textboxes, okay you need a conversion there, but in your table...why not use number types there?

Comment: check [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) method and [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) for your desire.

Comment: @mason sorry, if I wasn't clear . I want to put 0 in database when no data is inserted into the textboxes using only one function, and in the code  string other and tax are two textboxes. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Hello, There is a property in your "design table" called "Default Value" Is not better this option?

Comment: got it, thanks for all of your help and I am new to c#, so a little messed up. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following class:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static decimal ToTolerantDecimal(this string @this)
    {
       return string.IsNullOrEmpty(@this) ? 0.0m : decimal.Parse(@this);  
    }        
}
```

Now call as:

```
adp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@otherDeduct", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
     txtOtherDeduct.Text.ToTolerantDecimal();
```

I should point out that maybe the fact that you have `SqlDbType.VarChar` is slightly fishy.

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (Control in MyForm.Controls)
    {
      if (Control is TextBox)
    {
      string input = null;
      TextBox myTextBox = Control as TextBox;

      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myTextBox.Text))
      {
        input = "0";
      }
      else
      {
        input = myTextBox.Text;
      }

     //Never worked with this, maybe you have to edit it for your behaviour.
     adp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@taxDeduct", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = input;
    }
    }
```

Something like this? Else clarify your question please.

regards

Comment: Thanks, it worked... I just had to edit a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You mean a method something like this?

```
private decimal GetValue(string text)
{
    decimal result = 0;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
    {
        if (decimal.TryParse(text, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid value");
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
otherDeduct = ParseValue(txtOtherDeduct.Text);
taxDeduct = ParseValue(txtTaxDeduct.Text);

adp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@otherDeduct", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = otherDeduct;
adp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@taxDeduct", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = taxDeduct;

public double ParseValue(string value)
{
    return string.isNullOrEmpty(value) ? 0.0M : Convert.ToDecimal(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also add a "**DEFAULT '0.0M'**" constraint to the corresponding columns in your SQL Server table definition in the database.